# Break time into multiple times

Tags: php, time

Let's say I have an array with multiple instance of this class:

```
class Booking
    {
        public $status;
        public $start_time;
        public $end_time;
    }
```

- `array[0] $status = true $start_time = 13:30 $end_time = 14:00`
- `array[1] $status = true $start_time = 14:30 $end_time = 17:30`
- `array[2] $status = true $start_time = 20:30 $end_time = 21:30`
- `array[3] $status = true $start_time = 22:00 $end_time = 23:30`

How could I elaborate a function which given a time, like `12:00` and `23:00` would generate an array, with multiple instances of the same class, although with something like this:

- `array[0] $status = false $start_time = 12:00 $end_time = 13:30`
- `array[1] $status = true $start_time = 13:30 $end_time = 14:00`
- `array[2] $status = false $start_time = 14:00 $end_time = 14:30`
- `array[3] $status = true $start_time = 14:30 $end_time = 17:30`
- `array[4] $status = false $start_time = 17:30 $end_time = 20:30`
- `array[5] $status = true $start_time = 20:30 $end_time = 21:30`
- `array[6] $status = false $start_time = 21:30 $end_time = 22:00`
- `array[7] $status = true $start_time = 22:00 $end_time = 23:00`

Comment: I don't understand where's the complexity.

Comment: Good, then it would be an easy way for you get your answer checked.

Comment: I can't understand your logic, @BrunoKlein, please clarify your question with the logic.

Comment: @BrunoKlein, I'm not going to answer a "question" where you didn't even make an effort thinking of. My comment was a "polite" way to tell you to delve into your problem a bit more since it didn't require much.

Answer (score 1):

Look in this direction:

```
function generate($from, $till)
{
   $result = array();
   $t = $from;
   $status = true;
   while($t <= $till)
   {
     $result[] = new Booking($status, date('h:i', $t), date('h:i', $t+30*60));
     $t = $t+30*60;
     $status = !$status;
   }
   return $result;
}
```